# Tengo problema de GAS en el comando var id = e.parameter.id para AI2

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, google-api, parametros

```
function doGet (e) {
     var ss =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
     addUser(e, ss);
}

function doPost (e){
     var ss =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
     addUser(e, ss);
}

function addUser(e, ss) {
     var id =e.parameter.id;
     var nombre =e.parameter.nombre;
     ss.appendRow([id,nombre]);
}
```

Comment: Hola, es necesario que desarrolles más tu problema y formatees la parte del código para una fácil lectura y que alguien pueda ayudarte. Revisa [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta tenga mejor aceptación

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. En este sitio puedes editar tu pregunta. La publicación de respuestas sólo debe ser usada para publicar una respuesta a lo que se está preguntando. Por ejemplo, cuando una pregunta es sobre un problema que tiene solución, la respuesta deberá tener la solución al problema, pero cuando la pregunta es sobre problema que no tienen solución, la respuest diría esto incluyendo la explicación de ello.

Answer (score -1):

```
function doPost(e) {  
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); 
    var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Base");   
    return addUser(e,sheet);
}

function addUser(e,sheet) {  
    var id = e.parameter.id ;   
    var name = e.parameter.name ;
    sheet.appendRow([id,name]);  
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("Data successfully posted to sheet");
}
```

Comment: Hola @appcaucho. Bienvenido a **Stack Overflow**. Te invito realizar un [tour] para que conozca cómo funciona el sitio y ganes tu primera medalla. Por otra parte, también puede consultar [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) o leer todo sobre «[respondiendo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/answering)». Una respuesta no debe ser solo código, también debe explicarse cómo funciona.

Comment: Recuerda que las respuestas no solo van dirigidas a la persona que pregunta si no a usuarios de toda la comunidad que puedan tener las mismas dudas o problemas.

Comment: Aclara por favor si esto es la respuesta a tu pregunta, o es una aclaracion del problema. Ahora mismo no esta nada clara ni tu pregunta y esta publicacion.